# Creating method in model that returns a new instance with 'has_many through' child items populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First time building anything with Ruby on Rails and a bit lost on implementing "has_many through"

In this app I have Questions, DailyQuestionSets (there will be a single DailyQuestionSet for each day), and DailyQuestions (a many to many link table so that DailyQuestionSets can have multiple Questions.

(I realise these table/model names are bad, any suggestions for improving most welcome :)

I'm getting stuck on the step of creating a method on the DailyQuestionSet app called get_today_dailyquestionset that goes to the database to see if a DailyQuestionSet already exists for that day, if it doesn't, then create one, and return its .questions property populated with all of the Questions from the database.

(later I will change that from getting all questions to choosing 3 random questions each day)

```rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dailyquestions, foreign_key: 'dailyquestion_id'
  has_many :dailyquestionsets, :through => :dailyquestions
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end

class DailyQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :daily_question_set
  belongs_to :question
end

class DailyQuestionSet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :daily_questions, foreign_key: 'question_id'
  has_many :questions, :through => :daily_questions, :source => :question

  def self.get_today_dailyquestionset

    @dailyquestionset_list = DailyQuestionSet.where('posed_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).all

    if @dailyquestionset_list.count == 0

      @dailyquestionset = DailyQuestionSet.new(posed_date: DateTime.now)

      @dailyquestionset.save

    end

    @questionlist = Question.all

    @questionlist.each do |q|
      @dailyquestionset.questions << q

    end    
    return @dailyquestionset_list[0]  
  end  
end
```

I'm getting this error which I interpret to mean that the Question objects coming back from Question.all do not have a DailyQuestionSet associated with them. Which makes sense. But I can't find a way to create the many to many relationship for each question before adding it to the .questions array.

```
ERROR["test_create_daily_daily_question_set_if_not_already_existing", DailyQuestionSetTest, 1.0837379119993784]
 test_create_daily_daily_question_set_if_not_already_existing#DailyQuestionSetTest (1.08s)
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:         ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Daily question set must exist
            app/models/daily_question_set.rb:20:in `block in get_today_dailyquestionset'
            app/models/daily_question_set.rb:19:in `get_today_dailyquestionset'
            test/models/daily_question_set_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:DailyQuestionSetTest>'
```

Comment: Are you sure `@dailyquestionset.save` is returning true? maybe some error prevented it to be saved so no id. And, if count > 0, you are never setting `@dailyquestionset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, belongs_to validates if the association exist. You should add optional: true if you don't want this

```
class DailyQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :daily_question_set, optional: true
  belongs_to :question, optional: true
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34454

You should check that

```
@dailyquestionset.save
```

returns true, otherwise, a validation may have not passed. Or use save! to raise an exception.

Also, If `@dailyquestionset_list.count > 0`, then `@dailyquestionset` is nil.

p.d.: glad to help if you provide more information
p.d.d:  there is a type in

```
 @dailyquestionset_list = DailyQuestionSet.where('posed_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).all
```

I think it should be `posted_dated`

and

```
@dailyquestionset = DailyQuestionSet.new(posed_date: DateTime.now)
```

But that depends on the schema.

Comment: Thanks so much for the super helpful tips!

I have fixed some obvious errors that you pointed out :) like checking @dailyquestionset for nil and changing to @dailyquestionset.save! to make sure it's actually saving

posed_date isn't a typo, just my oddly named database column name for when the questionset was asked

I have tried adding optional: true to the DailyQuestion model but then I get an error saying "method .questions is not defined"

Any more thoughts most appreciated!

Comment: Also - one thing I'm a bit confused about is how this DailyQuestions link table is actually used in the model code. I can see adding Questions to a DailyQuestionSet, but it's actually the DailyQuestions table that is driving the many to many relationship. So if I have an existing Question and DailyQuestionSet, what would be the right code to link them?

Comment: You should start using byebug. This is a debugging gem that allows you to stop the code right before the error, so you can inspect variables and take a deeper look at what is going on. So if you are getting "method .questions is not defined"  error, then @dailyquestionset is not what you thing it is.

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Comment: As for your other question:
The key here is that you have a has_many :through association. 
So when you add a question to DailyQuestionSet and save it, what rails does under the hood is to create a DailyQuestion object that binds the question and the DailyQuestionSet.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association